# how do i keep a specific window of another program from stealing focus (C# ?)

Tags: c#, focus-stealing

i'm using a certain program that has a multitude of windows and each and every one of those windows might steal focus at certain times (mostly when they open).
i would like to prevent a specific window from stealing focus when it opens (and also at other times, but that's less important and i can probably figure it out on my own if i'm given the solution for the main problem). i would like doing it in C# but any other programming language is probably good as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent other apps from stealing the focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086477/how-can-i-prevent-other-apps-from-stealing-the-focus)

Answer (score 1):

This is a recurring and old question.

Raymond Chen addressed it on his blog a while ago:

[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Essentially, it just ends up being an arms race.

Comment: i don't think you really read my question.
i don't want any and all programs to never get focus, i want a specific window to not steal focus when it opens (which it shouldn't steal in the first place), for a specific amount of time (like 1 second, so all the load stuff is done and it'll only steal focus when it needs input).

Comment: also i think this is supposed to keep any window from stealing focus:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms633532.aspx