# activate windows application always

Tags: vb.net

i have created an windows application, i have one textbox in form1. if i run the application it works fine ,

i have set in `textbox_lostfocus` event-

```
Private Sub txtCardID_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCardID.LostFocus

    txtCardID.Focus()

End Sub
```

And in form deactivate event -

```
Private Sub frmPlay_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate

    txtCardID_LostFocus(sender, e)
    Me.Activate()
End Sub
```

but my problem is when i click other application say-paint,or something else that becomes activate and my application loss focus

when i click my form it activate and works

i need always my form to be activated and what ever key clicked the value should enter in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the post "[How can I prevent other apps from stealing the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086477/how-can-i-prevent-other-apps-from-stealing-the-focus)"

Or try this if not there are more than controls in your form that txtCardID:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private fin As Boolean

    Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate

        Do
            Me.Activate()
            My.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until fin

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        fin = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i used your sets of code but it restricts all application to perform its action. for eg:if i run my program it runs and i go what i need but i does'nt allow anything to work so i coudl not make my program to stop

Comment: what i all need is my form should always be active and also it allows other application to work

Comment: if you allow another application has the focus (for example with a button), then your application will be disabled and therefore the `txtCardID` textbox lose focus :(

Comment: Hi  Aprendiendo.NET, i made my form activate when it is in unfocused by using hotkeys,if key-g is pressed my app will get activated and i ll use it ,if i use any app like paint or anything else and i press key-g my app will get focused. so that my app get focused at same time other app also working   my reference link is-http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94406-global-hotkey/

Comment: any ways thank you for your valuable ideas it helped me lot.thank you once again